# Compute $\int\limits_0^{\infty}\frac{(v - \lambda)^2}\lambda\exp(\frac {\text -v}{\lambda}) \,\mathrm dv$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, gamma-function

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{(v - \lambda)^2}\lambda\exp(\frac {\text -v}{\lambda})
\,\mathrm dv$$

$$t=\frac {\text -v}{\lambda}$$
$$dt=\frac {\text -dv}{\lambda}$$

$$=-\lambda\int_{-\infty}^{0}\frac{(-\lambda t - \lambda)^2}\lambda\exp(t)
\,\mathrm dt$$

How should I do to continue?

Comment: Is there a typo? As written this looks divergent

Comment: Where is the typo?

Comment: What happens to the integral as $v \to -\infty$ for $\lambda > 0$?

Comment: Are you asking about evaluating the integral on $(-\infty, +\infty),~(-\infty, 0)$ or $(0, +\infty)$?

Comment: @O.spectrum, the integral converges only for $\lambda\in\mathbb{R^{+}}$ and range is $(0,\infty)$

Comment: @RAHUL yeah, that is why I'm asking

Comment: It's easiest not to choose a substitution that changes the variable's sign. As long as you know $\int_0^\infty x^ne^{-x}dx=n!$, you can finish this.

Comment: Take @J.G.'s guidance: expand $(v - \lambda)^2$ to expose powers of $v$, then take advantage of the standard relation he states. Or if you prefer something different you can proceed directly integrating by parts a few times.

Answer (score 2):

First, it seems like, if you are trying to evaluate $\int\limits_{-\infty}^{0}\frac{(v-\lambda)^2}{\lambda}\cdot e^{\frac{-v}{\lambda}}dv$, then the answer is that it simply diverges, as well, as if the bounds for integration were $(-\infty, +\infty)$, as $e^{\frac{-v}{\lambda}} \to +\infty,~\text{as }v \to -\infty$. Moreover, in your $t$-substitution, you have forgotten to change the integration bounds.

Now, let's assume, that you are looking for $\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{(v-\lambda)^2}{\lambda}\cdot e^{\frac{-v}{\lambda}}dv$. Then, if (as correctly mentioned by @RAHUL) $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}^+$:

$$
\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{(v-\lambda)^2}{\lambda}\cdot e^{\frac{-v}{\lambda}}d v~=~\left[t = \frac{-v}{\lambda},~d t = -\frac{dv}{\lambda} \biggm\vert~v = -\lambda t,~d v = -\lambda d t\right] = \\=(\text{Since we swap zero to be the upper bound, we have to change the sign}) = -1\cdot(-\lambda)\cdot\\\cdot\int\limits_{-\infty}^{0}\frac{(-\lambda t-\lambda)^2}{\lambda}\cdot e^{t}d t = \lambda^2 \int\limits_{-\infty}^{0}(t+1)^2 e^{t}d t = \lambda^2 \cdot\\\cdot\left(\int\limits_{-\infty}^{0}e^t \cdot t^2~dt + 2\int\limits_{-\infty}^{0}e^t \cdot t~dt + \int\limits_{-\infty}^{0}e^td t\right) = \left[\text{Integrating by parts}\right] = \\=\lambda^2\left(e^tt^2\biggm\vert^{0}_{\lim\limits_{n\to-\infty}(n)} - \int\limits_{-\infty}^{0}e^t \cdot 2t~d t + 2\int\limits_{-\infty}^{0}e^t \cdot t~d t \int\limits_{-\infty}^{0}e^t dt \right) =\\= [\text{As }e^t \text{ has higher convergence rate to }0\text{ then the divergence rate of } t^2 \text{ at }-\infty]=\\=\lambda^2\left([0 - 0] + \int\limits_{-\infty}^0 e^t dt \right) = \lambda^2 \cdot \lim\limits_{n\to-\infty}\left(e^t\biggm\vert^{0}_{n}\right) = \lambda^2 \cdot (1 - 0) = \lambda^2.
$$

Comment: Thank you@O.spectrum. Yes you are right.I misspelled the bounds. but in my book for bounds $\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty}$ wrote that the answer is $\lambda^2$.

Comment: No problem! Yeah, I think, that is right that answer is $\lambda^2$ with no minus,, as far as changing the integration bounds would have also changed the $\lambda$ sign, let me review my question, so that I will find the mistake and correct it :)

Comment: @MohammadrezaMozafarinia Fixed! Now it seems alright

Comment: thanks a million.

Comment: @MohammadrezaMozafarinia you are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Leaving out the minus sign, the substitution
$$u = \frac{v}{\lambda}, \qquad du = \frac{dv}{\lambda}$$ transforms the integral (provided that $\lambda > 0$, lest the integral diverge) to
$$\lambda^2 \int_0^\infty (u - 1)^2 e^u \,du .$$
Expanding gives $$\lambda^2 \left[\int_0^\infty u^2 e^{-u} \,du - 2 \int_0^\infty u e^{-u} \,du + \int_0^\infty e^{-u} \,du \right] .$$
Now, as suggested in the comments, you can use the fact that for nonnegative integers $n$,
$$\int_0^\infty u^n e^{-n} \,du = n! ,$$
which can be shown, e.g., with induction and integration by parts.